# Range of characters for each language

Tags: unicode

It seems that malayalam language characters can be found between 3328 to 3456 as per this page...

https://github.com/qburst/common-crawl-malayalam/blob/master/src/process_warc_batch.py

```
malayalam_unicode_decimal_list = list(range(3328, 3456)) + [8204, 8205]

def is_char_malayalam(c):
    if ord(c) in malayalam_unicode_decimal_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I will like to know what is the range for other languages like Gujarati or hindi.

---

As suggested in the comment, I have calculated the ranges in python.

Devnagari:

```
ord("ऀ")
ord("ॿ")
```

> range(2304, 2432)

Gujarati:

```
ord("઀")
ord("૿")
```

> range(2688, 2816)

Not sure if this is correct.

Comment: https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block In *List of blocks* section there’s a table.

Comment: Does it mean range(2304, 2432) correct for devnagari?

Comment: Cannot answer. I’m not expert of this domain, just paste some links for your reference.

Comment: Go to the standard: http://www.unicode.org/charts/